# How can I use the KML or geojson to display in List view?

Tags: android, json, openstreetmap, kml, osmdroid

I have been working with osmbonus library and osmdroid library tutorial. I have download the KML and json file in my sd card and now I want to list all the information in list view.

like:
name = xyz school
amenity = school
addr:street = abc
opening_hours : Su-Fr 22:00-04:00

The kml file is in format:

```
<Placemark id="mId">
<Point>
<coordinates>85.0960383,27.6345759,0.0 </coordinates>
</Point>
<ExtendedData>
<Data name="addr:postcode"><value>44100</value></Data>
<Data name="name:en"><value>Palung Modern English Secondary School</value></Data>
<Data name="amenity"><value>school</value></Data>
<Data name="addr:street"><value>Tribhuvan Highway</value></Data>
<Data name="opening_hours"><value>Su-Fr 22:00-04:00</value></Data>
</ExtendedData>
</Placemark>
```

I have use the code like this to store the file

```
//file at storage/sdcard0/kml
            mKmlDocument.saveAsKML(mKmlDocument.getDefaultPathForAndroid("my_route.kml"));
// Loading and saving of GeoJSON content
            mKmlDocument.saveAsGeoJSON(mKmlDocument.getDefaultPathForAndroid("my_route.json"));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Reading in the KML file and populating the list view doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know Android ListView mechanisms:

Access to the placemark extended data. Your placemark is the unique feature inside your KML document, so:

```
KmlPlacemark placemark = (KmlPlacemark)mKmlDocument.mKmlRoot.mItems.get(0);
HashMap<String, String> extendedData = placemark.mExtendedData;
```

Then parse its extendedData (see [KmlFeature.getExtendedDataAsText](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/blob/master/OSMBonusPack/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/kml/KmlFeature.java) source code if you need an example), and populate your ListView with that.